# Connect to Wi-Fi via terminal while having two Wi-Fi receivers

Tags: command-line, wireless

Searched but didn't find similar question.
I know the process to connect via terminal to a wifi. But if I have two receivers how do I specify which receiver connects to network1 and the other to network2.

Comment: With the SSID. That says which one.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting